# ToastContainer - Erro ao dar um build --prod

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-8

Quando rodo o projeto em *dev* funciona perfeitamente, quando tento dar o *build* em *prod*, da esse erro...

> WARNING in Invalid animation value at 221:41. Ignoring. < **Esse eu resolvi**
>
> ERROR in Error during template compile of 'ToastContainer'
>
> Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'trigger' was called.

Como posso resolver? Quais arquivos precisam para que me ajudem?

**PS:** Utilizo a versão 8.2 do Angular.

-> toast-container.component.d.ts

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef, NgZone, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { AnimationEvent } from '@angular/animations'
import { Toast } from './toast';
import { ToastOptions } from './toast-options';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
export declare class ToastContainer implements OnDestroy {
    private sanitizer;
    private cdr;
    private _zone;
    position: string;
    messageClass: string;
    titleClass: string;
    positionClass: string;
    maxShown: number;
    newestOnTop: boolean;
    animate: string;
    toasts: Toast[];
    private _fresh;
    private onToastClicked;
    private _onEnter;
    private _onExit;
    constructor(sanitizer: DomSanitizer, cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, _zone: NgZone, options: ToastOptions);
    onEnter(): Observable<void>;
    onExit(): Observable<void>;
    addToast(toast: Toast): void;
    removeToast(toast: Toast): void;
    removeAllToasts(): void;
    clicked(toast: Toast): void;
    anyToast(): boolean;
    findToast(toastId: number): Toast | void;
    onAnimationEnd(event: AnimationEvent): void;
    private _ngExit();
    ngOnDestroy(): void;
}
```

**EDIT**

Dei o comando `ng build --prod --verbose`, obtive:

```
29110ms building
4ms finish module graph
2ms sealing
1ms basic dependencies optimization
2ms dependencies optimization
1ms advanced dependencies optimization
1ms after dependencies optimization
16ms chunk graph
1ms after chunk graph
1ms optimizing
1ms basic module optimization
1ms module optimization
3ms advanced module optimization
1ms after module optimization
2ms basic chunk optimization
2ms chunk optimization
7ms advanced chunk optimization
3ms after chunk optimization
1ms module and chunk tree optimization
2ms after module and chunk tree optimization
9ms basic chunk modules optimization
2ms chunk modules optimization
2ms advanced chunk modules optimization
2ms after chunk modules optimization
2ms module reviving
2ms module order optimization
1ms advanced module order optimization
2ms before module ids
1ms module ids
2ms module id optimization
2ms chunk reviving
2ms chunk order optimization
2ms before chunk ids
2ms chunk id optimization
3ms after chunk id optimization
6ms hashing
17ms content hashing
1ms after hashing
4ms module assets processing
20ms chunk assets processing
14ms additional chunk assets processing
7ms additional asset processing
8127ms chunk asset optimization
6ms after chunk asset optimization
2ms asset optimization
1ms after asset optimization
3ms after seal
Hash: 391c2bb4596ef533199a
Version: webpack 4.39.1
Time: 37984ms
Built at: 2019-08-08 11:25:05
                                                 Asset       Size   Chunks  Chunk Names
                                  3rdpartylicenses.txt   8.74 KiB
           Simple-Line-Icons.0bbfc705e37a927ce2ae.woff   52.2 KiB
          Simple-Line-Icons.6ac7320f709ffd2784b4.woff2   25.8 KiB
            Simple-Line-Icons.b2892aa62b0fb2c21c8d.ttf   52.1 KiB
            Simple-Line-Icons.dacd16c9a3d2cb61b472.eot   52.3 KiB
            Simple-Line-Icons.de8ad55bfeaebbe67c5b.svg    193 KiB
                custom-select.33d0b67c047e466b46c4.png   14.6 KiB
                       danger.f6dc099240cc766d0ba0.svg  218 bytes
                  data-table.246ea8fa6c452b0f3c4f.woff   1.59 KiB
                   data-table.b0aebd744ce7adb780a9.svg    2.6 KiB
                   data-table.bce071e976865da51100.eot   2.46 KiB
                   data-table.c8c6d300cb7abb9f36e8.ttf    2.3 KiB
                    dxicons.71e4862eef32c43eca3f.woff2   18.6 KiB
                     dxicons.dffa1b6f8175e126e4fd.woff   23.8 KiB
                      dxicons.e7b052cb56375958973b.ttf   47.6 KiB
                     error-bg.49225702da79d063db36.jpg    220 KiB
          fontawesome-webfont.674f50d287a8c48dc19b.eot    162 KiB
          fontawesome-webfont.acf3dcb7ff752b5296ca.svg    437 KiB
        fontawesome-webfont.af7ae505a9eed503f8b8.woff2   75.4 KiB
          fontawesome-webfont.b06871f281fee6b241d6.ttf    162 KiB
         fontawesome-webfont.fee66e712a8a08eef580.woff   95.7 KiB
                   main-es2015.de3c2c9a80e4d7e26bfa.js  128 bytes        1  main
 materialdesignicons-webfont.4fed03f1e0fb21693813.woff    127 KiB
  materialdesignicons-webfont.8a4927f053e671531ae9.svg   1.89 MiB
  materialdesignicons-webfont.a65b9561e6b00796ee6a.ttf    255 KiB
  materialdesignicons-webfont.b8695cc16b97f1bd9744.eot    255 KiB
materialdesignicons-webfont.cc3cf0bd5af9550e4d18.woff2   97.4 KiB
                   megamenubg.8f281bd48eae0793a7c5.jpg   24.2 KiB
              polyfills-es2015.519b047b6793c5217abe.js  130 bytes        2  polyfills
                runtime-es2015.e333bd6046f4cba4498e.js   1.45 KiB        0  runtime
                       scripts.6c269433372af48d437d.js    226 KiB  scripts  scripts
                       shape1.ae011d37cceae760ab31.svg  759 bytes
                       styles.17177fd07e5d6feae9fd.css   1.07 MiB        3  styles
                      success.de4ee7ad58f75b356c97.svg  194 bytes
                      themify.2c454669bdf3aebf32a1.eot   76.9 KiB
                     themify.a1ecc3b826d01251eddd.woff   54.8 KiB
                      themify.cba68f986e60df8c74f4.svg    229 KiB
                      themify.e23a7dcaefbde4e74e26.ttf   76.7 KiB
                     tooltip1.0fe468c244a79221d05c.svg  535 bytes
      ui-icons_444444_256x240.a4c733ec4baef9ad3896.png   3.67 KiB
      ui-icons_555555_256x240.971364734f3b603e5d36.png   3.67 KiB
      ui-icons_777620_256x240.208a290102a4ada58a04.png   3.67 KiB
      ui-icons_777777_256x240.73a1fd052c9d84c0ee0b.png   3.67 KiB
      ui-icons_cc0000_256x240.0de3b51742ed3ac61435.png   3.67 KiB
      ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.bf27228a7d3957983584.png   3.67 KiB
                      warning.7a3f95cec4b5847d44d1.svg  267 bytes
Entrypoint main = runtime-es2015.e333bd6046f4cba4498e.js main-es2015.de3c2c9a80e4d7e26bfa.js
Entrypoint polyfills = runtime-es2015.e333bd6046f4cba4498e.js polyfills-es2015.519b047b6793c5217abe.js
Entrypoint styles = runtime-es2015.e333bd6046f4cba4498e.js styles.17177fd07e5d6feae9fd.css
Entrypoint scripts = scripts.6c269433372af48d437d.js
chunk    {0} runtime-es2015.e333bd6046f4cba4498e.js (runtime) 0 bytes ={1}= ={2}= ={3}= [entry] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main-es2015.de3c2c9a80e4d7e26bfa.js (main) 28 bytes ={0}= [initial] [rendered]
 [0] multi ./src/main.ts 28 bytes {1} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     multi entry
 [zUnb] ./src/main.ts 0 bytes {1} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\ meupc\main\src\main.ts [0] multi ./src/main.ts main[0]
chunk    {2} polyfills-es2015.519b047b6793c5217abe.js (polyfills) 28 bytes ={0}= [initial] [rendered]
 [1] multi ./src/polyfills.ts 28 bytes {2} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     multi entry
 [hN/g] ./src/polyfills.ts 0 bytes {2} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\ meupc\main\src\polyfills.ts [1] multi ./src/polyfills.ts polyfills[0]
chunk    {3} styles.17177fd07e5d6feae9fd.css (styles) 1.26 MiB ={0}= [initial] [rendered]
 [2] multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css ./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./src/assets/scss/style.scss ./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css 172 bytes {3} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     multi entry
 [] css ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./src/styles.css 18.4 KiB {3}
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     [OmL/] ./src/styles.css
 [] css ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 153 KiB {3}
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     [q4sD] ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
 [] css ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css 8.1 KiB {3}
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     [KEkg] ./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css
 [] css ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css 12.7 KiB {3}
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     [VjLz] ./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css
 [] css ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css 24.3 KiB {3}
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     [gJae] ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css
 [] css ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css 548 bytes {3}
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     [Ma1P] ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css
 [] css ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./src/assets/scss/style.scss 364 KiB {3}
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     [eKdF] ./src/assets/scss/style.scss
 [] css ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss 3.85 KiB {3}
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     [98WW] ./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss
 [] css ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css 186 KiB {3}
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     [SDvI] ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css
 [] css ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css 1.96 KiB {3}
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     [1vva] ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css
 [] css ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css 474 KiB {3}
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     [ru2K] ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css
 [] css ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css 39.9 KiB {3}
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     [v+Tf] ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css
 [] css ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??extracted!./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css 6.21 KiB {3}
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     [G9EY] ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css
 [1vva] ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css 39 bytes {3} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\ meupc\main\node_modules\devextreme\dist\css\dx.spa.css [2] multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css ./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./src/assets/scss/style.scss ./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css styles[9]
 [98WW] ./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss 39 bytes {3} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\ meupc\main\src\assets\scss\colors\blue.scss [2] multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css ./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css
./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./src/assets/scss/style.scss ./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css styles[7]
 [G9EY] ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css 39 bytes {3} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\ meupc\main\node_modules\ngx-toastr\toastr.css [2] multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css ./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./src/assets/scss/style.scss ./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css styles[12]
 [KEkg] ./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css 39 bytes {3} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\ meupc\main\node_modules\angular-calendar\css\angular-calendar.css [2] multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css ./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./src/assets/scss/style.scss ./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css styles[2]
 [Ma1P] ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css 39 bytes {3} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\ meupc\main\node_modules\dragula\dist\dragula.css [2] multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css ./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./src/assets/scss/style.scss ./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css styles[5]
 [OmL/] ./src/styles.css 39 bytes {3} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\ meupc\main\src\styles.css [2] multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css ./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./src/assets/scss/style.scss ./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css styles[0]
 [SDvI] ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css 39 bytes {3} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\ meupc\main\node_modules\devextreme\dist\css\dx.common.css [2] multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css ./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./src/assets/scss/style.scss ./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css styles[8]
 [VjLz] ./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css 39 bytes {3} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\ meupc\main\node_modules\chartist\dist\chartist.css [2] multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css ./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./src/assets/scss/style.scss ./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css styles[3]
 [eKdF] ./src/assets/scss/style.scss 39 bytes {3} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\ meupc\main\src\assets\scss\style.scss [2] multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css ./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./src/assets/scss/style.scss ./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css styles[6]
 [gJae] ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css 39 bytes {3} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\ meupc\main\node_modules\quill\dist\quill.snow.css [2] multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css ./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./src/assets/scss/style.scss ./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css styles[4]
 [q4sD] ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 39 bytes {3} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\ meupc\main\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css [2] multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css ./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./src/assets/scss/style.scss ./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css styles[1]
 [ru2K] ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css 39 bytes {3} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\ meupc\main\node_modules\devextreme\dist\css\dx.light.css [2] multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css ./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./src/assets/scss/style.scss ./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css styles[10]
 [v+Tf] ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css 39 bytes {3} [built]
     ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
     single entry C:\ meupc\main\node_modules\jquery-ui\themes\base\all.css [2] multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css ./node_modules/chartist/dist/chartist.css ./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css ./node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css ./src/assets/scss/style.scss ./src/assets/scss/colors/blue.scss ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.spa.css ./node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css ./node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css styles[11]
chunk {scripts} scripts.6c269433372af48d437d.js (scripts) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

WARNING in Invalid animation value at 221:41. Ignoring.

WARNING in Terser Plugin: Dropping side-effect-free statement [scripts.6c269433372af48d437d.js:2,66549]

WARNING in Terser Plugin: Dropping unreachable code [scripts.6c269433372af48d437d.js:2,83630]

WARNING in Terser Plugin: Declarations in unreachable code! [scripts.6c269433372af48d437d.js:2,83630]

WARNING in Terser Plugin: Dropping duplicated definition of variable m [scripts.6c269433372af48d437d.js:29,36]

WARNING in Terser Plugin: Dropping duplicated definition of variable c [scripts.6c269433372af48d437d.js:29,281]

WARNING in Terser Plugin: Dropping duplicated definition of variable h [scripts.6c269433372af48d437d.js:30,46]

WARNING in Terser Plugin: Dropping side-effect-free statement [scripts.6c269433372af48d437d.js:34,5706]

ERROR in Error during template compile of 'ToastContainer'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'trigger' was called.
```